# Limiting the amount of images from to be loaded from a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, path, python-imaging-library

I have 50 images inside a folder, but for testing i'll need to choose between different sizes, for instance sometimes ill need just 10 images from the folder, and some times ill need 11 or 15. But what i am doing right now is loading all images inside a given folder path. Which in turn, would make me create a new folder with the desired amount of images i would like to load a different amount of images, which is optimal.

This is the current way im doing to load all images:

```
def loadImages(path):

    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        img = PImage.open(path + image)
        arr = np.array(img)
        loadedImages.append(arr)


    return loadedImages
```

Then i'd go and do

`images = loadImages('imgfolder')`, which would load everything inside the folder, when i just want the amount i really need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a second parameter to the funcion, which is the maximum size in `MegaByte`:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image    

def loadImages(path, max_size):

    imagesList = os.listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    temp_size = 0

    for image in imagesList:
        os.chdir(path)
        temp_size += os.path.getsize(image)
        if temp_size > max_size*1000000:
            break           
        img = Image.open(path + image)
        arr = np.array(img)
        loadedImages.append(arr)

    return loadedImages 


loadImages(path, 50)
```

If you want to set the `number` of pictures you can add a second parameter as max_num:

```
def loadImages(path, max_num):

    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []

    for i, image in enumerate(imagesList):
        if i == max_num:
            break
        img = PImage.open(path + image)
        arr = np.array(img)
        loadedImages.append(arr)

    return loadedImages 

loadImages(path, 10)
```

Comment: nice! very simple and a lot helpful